# $p$ divides $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^p)^n $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to prove this.

Let $p> 2$ be an odd prime and let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that

$p$ divides $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^p)^n $

Hint: Be $k=p^n$ and evaluate $d^k+(p-d)^k$ use the binomial theorem.

Thanks you for help me!

Comment: Change title to describe content of question.

Comment: What's $d{}{}$?

Comment: Use the hint you are given, use the binomial theorem to write out $(p-d)^k$ , then work out divisibility..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\gcd(p,k)=1, \forall k=\overline{1,p-1}$, from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)
$$k^p\equiv k \pmod{p} \Rightarrow (k^p)^n\equiv k^n \pmod{p}$$
then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(k^p)^n\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^n \pmod{p}$$
As **Lubin** showed, the statement **isn't always true**. However, it works for $n=1$ because
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k=\frac{p(p-1)}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
It works for $n=3$, [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^3=\left(\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\right)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
And generally, for any $n=2q+1$, i.e. odd, because, due to [binomial expantion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{2q+1}=(1+(p-1)^{2q+1}) + (2^{2q+1}+(p-2)^{2q+1})+ (3^{2q+1}+(p-3)^{2q+1})+...+\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^{2q+1}+\left(p-\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^{2q+1}\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: How can I replace the module because I can not use it?

Comment: @BellaPatarroyo it's not too difficult, $K \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is similar to $p | K$ or $p$ divides $K$.

Comment: why gcd(p,k)=1?

Comment: Because $k<p$ and $p$ is prime

Answer (score 1):

It’s not true, as you see from the example $p=3$, $n=2$. In general, if $n$ is a multiple of $p-1$, you’re taking (modulo $p$) the sum of $1$ just $p-1$ times, giving a sum that’s $\equiv-1\pmod p$.