# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^i$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that $$1^i + 2^i + \cdots + (p-1)^i \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ for all $i$, $1 \le i \le (p-2)$.

If $i$ is odd, then we are done, since $j^i + (p-j)^i \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for every $j$. But how can we prove this if $i$ is even?
Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777526/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-and-k-an-integer-with-0kp-1-then-1k-2k-ldot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$p$ divides $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^p)^n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172107/p-divides-sum-limits-k-1p-1-kpn) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894860/show-that-sum-limits-i-1p-ip-is-divisible-by-p-for-all-primes-p/2894885#2894885)

Comment: @rtybase Neither of these solve the problem. The answers of the first post aren’t all that great, and the answers of the second post solve only the case where $i$ is odd.

Comment: @URL I seriously insist you look at the links again.

Comment: @rtybase I correct myself: the answers in the second post solve only the even more trivial case $i=p$.

Comment: @URL and Lubin's answer in the 1st link ...

Comment: @rtybase Lubin states that the problem is **false** when $p-1\mid i$. This problem deals only with $1\leq i\leq(p-2)$.

Comment: @URL Ok, vote to close this question using lab's link ...

Comment: @rtybase I hadn’t seen that one: this question is definitely a dupe of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\xi$ a [Primitive Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $\text{mod }p$. In particular, $\xi^i\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Therefore, $$1^i+2^i+\ldots+(p-1)^i\equiv\xi^0+\xi^i+\xi^{2i}+\ldots+\xi^{(p-2)i}\equiv\left(\xi^{(p-1)i}-1\right)\left(\xi^i-1\right)^{-1}\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$ $\blacksquare$